# How to add an unbroken line in bash starting from end of my left hand PS1 text to the right hand side

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I am having trouble wrapping my mind around this little problem

Basically Im using this bash PS1 script because its kinda cool:

```
PS1="\n \[\033[0;34m\]╭─────\[\033[0;31m\]\[\033[0;37m\]\[\033[41m\] \u \[\033[0m\]\[\033[0;31m\]\[\033[0;34m\]─────\[\033[0;32m\]\[\033[0;30m\]\[\033[42m\] \w \[\033[0m\]\[\033[0;32m\] \n \[\033[0;34m\]╰ \[\033[1;36m\]\$ \[\033[0m\]"
```

looks like this:

[image: bash like powerline]

What I want to do is print a time stamp on the right hand side with a solid line connecting the end of the left side to the beginning of the right side of the text, for example:

```
ben @ local ------------------------------------------12:00pm
```

I tried doing this:

```
$(printf '%*s' $COLUMNS  '-')
```

but that obviously just creates a whole new line filled with the dashes.

How do I get the value of where the curser left off, I see `tput sc` but I don't understand how to use that in a variable? Then print the lines, leaving maybe 5 characters on the right side for the time.

This is my first foray into bash scripting so forgive my ignorance.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, you have to strip escape sequences from the prompt string and expand it to get the real length to subtract the column length.

```
prompt_handler(){
    local A="$2[\A]"

    while [[ $A =~ \\[\x1b\\[[0-9\;]*m\\] ]]; do
       A=${A//"${BASH_REMATCH}"}
    done

    A=${A@P} \
    A=$((COLUMNS-${#A}))

    eval printf \
        -v A ─%.s {1..$A}

    PS1="$1$2${A}[\A]$3"
}

PROMPT_COMMAND='prompt_handler "\n" " \[\033[0;34m\]╭─────\[\033[0;31m\]\[\033[0;37m\]\[\033[41m\] \u \[\033[0m\]\[\033[0;31m\]\[\033[0;34m\]─────\[\033[0;32m\]\[\033[0;30m\]\[\033[42m\] \w \[\033[0m\]\[\033[0;32m\]" "\n \[\033[0;34m\]╰ \[\033[1;36m\]\$ \[\033[0m\]"'
```

Comment: This is really neat! It would benefit from some explanation though since you are using various bash features that will not be known by many. I had to look up the `${A@P}`, for instance, to learn that it is a special expansion mode that makes the variable be expanded as though it were a prompt string.